# Vuejs Single-file-component not Rendered in Page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

No errors in browser, Webpack compiles successfully, but the "hello from dashboard" doesn't show up in the page.

I'm using Vue v2.6

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.component('dashboard', require('@comp/dashboard.vue').default);

const app = require('@/App.vue').default; // this app component works fine

import "./css/app.css"

new Vue({
  render: h => h(app) // this app component works fine
}).$mount('#app')
```

dashboard.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    Hello from dashboard
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "dashboard"
}
</script>
```

index.html

```
<body>
<div id="app">
    <dashboard></dashboard>
</div>
</body>
```

This is the rendered HTML from the browser, However, "hello from dashboard" is not there :(

```
<body>
<div id="app">
    <dashboard></dashboard>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: i see nothing wrong in your code 
can you make sandbox for demo..

Comment: didnt know a way for online sandbox with bundles and stuff, it is here https://github.com/Z3yko/vue-app, many thanks

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya You missed the HTML code, it´s wrong to put any kind of code into the `<div id="app">`, because it will be replaced. So with `<dashboard>`, that´s why it dont show.

Answer (score 2):

### You have the root file "App.vue" mounted in the div id = "app", so the "dashboard" needs to be added to App.vue to see its contents.

```html
// App.vue
<template>
  <dashboard />
</template>

<script>
  export default {};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

In this code, you have connected a component globally, which will be available in App.vue or another child component

```
Vue.component('dashboard', require('@comp/dashboard.vue').default);
```

Comment: Right that's my point, "globaly" so I should be able to use it in index.html also right? why is that not working, and Im registering it to the instance not to App component

Comment: you should not use anything inside div#app it will be replaced

Comment: @manhoty [index.html](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html) acts as a start file, in which no application development is carried out, so all the logic and architecture of the application takes place in the src/ folder next to the root App.vue document.
Perhaps you want to include vue as a [library](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CDN), then you can use components in html files. For example, how is it [herel](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/vuejs/vuejs.org/tree/master/src/v2/examples/vue-20-hello-world?file=/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I assume its the path you are missing so i added a / before comp. Because you stated the App.vue works.

```js
Vue.component('dashboard', require('@/comp/dashboard.vue').default);
```

Comment: thnaks but no im setting the alias this way and it's resolving